# Remove all unused pictures

Tags: magento2

Is there any way I can see and delete all pictures that are not in use in pub/media folder?
I found a couple of modules but all are just for deleted products and I want to include the ones at wysiwyg folder too, like from old homepages and pages that got new pictures. It would be painful and time consuming to go one by one checking if it is in use and delete by hand.

Thanks in advance :D

Best regards,
Rui Silva

Comment: You would like to remove unwanted images for catalog products?

Comment: if yes you can try this module https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner using this module you can remove unwanted catalog images for the products

Comment: But you have to try it on local instance first and verify the results take backups aswell
1. php/magento eav:media:remove-unused  --dry-run    (it will show you the resutls)
2. php/magento eav:media:remove-unused                        (remove)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all pub/media images as this way

**Admin** ==> **Content** ==> **Blocks** under '**Elements**' ==> Click To **New Block** ==> Click on '**Insert Image**' button then you got a section as below and you need go to separate folder and **delete** the images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But there how do I know if the image is being used somewhere?